# Rename built-in functions w/o using 3rd party add-on?

Tags: php, function, rename, built-in

I'd like to preface the built-in PHP functions in my code with "php_" to simply make it easier to identify them as such, and to do so without using a 3rd party add-on. So my first attempt at it was this:

```
<?php
define('php_date_default_timezone_set', 'date_default_timezone_set');
define('php_date', 'date');

php_date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo php_date('l, F j, Y \a\t g:i:s a');
?>
```

This causes the error,

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function php_date

One [ugly] way to do this that actually works is:

```
<?php
define('php_', '');

php_.date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo php_.date('l, F j, Y \a\t g:i:s a');

?>
```

I suspect there is more than one way to do it; how would you do it?

Comment: It'd be a lot easier to do the reverse and leave PHP functions as is, and make your own code use a namespace or similar so they always have a designation

Comment: Yes, I agree, and it is something I'm already doing.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the functions in your own custom functions. Mark Ormston's method is better though.

```
function php_date_default_timezone_set($timezone)
{
    date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
}

function php_date($date) 
{
    date($date);
}
```